# Build rpm containing pythons script and dependent python modules

Tags: python, linux, build, rpm, rpmbuild

I want to build a rpm which will contains my

1. python script
2. python dependent modules.

I want to install this rpm in my production environment which have no network, also cannot use/install pip.

Adding my spec file below. It creates the rpm but when I try to run it just mentions

error: Failed dependencies:

```
python-cassandra-driver is needed by stats-1.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64
```

**NOTE** I want the rpm to contain installation of my python modules as well as my python script, so that I can simply run my script on production with installing any module manually.

SPEC

```
Name:           stats
Version:        1.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Summary of Customer stats

License:       ***
URL:           ***
Source0:        %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz

Requires: python-cassandra-driver

%description
Script that shows stats of customer on a particular pod

%prep
%setup -q

%build
%{__python} setup.py build

%install
%{__python} setup.py install --skip-build --root $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%{python_sitelib}/*

%changelog
```

Comment: No, you really do not want that. What you really want it to keep your spec as is and then create python-cassandra-driver rpm (you can utilize pyp2rpm for that).

Comment: I tried but the spec file generated gives me many other dependencies to take care of now.

Comment: If you would the way "one rpm with everything" you would have to add those dependencies there as well.